# Unable to restart ssh on Mac OS Sierra - launchctl unload Could not find specified service

Tags: mac, ssh, port-forwarding

I am trying to tunnel into a remote EC2 bastion server via `ssh` because I need to [connect to a DB behind a firewall](http://blog.trackets.com/2014/05/17/ssh-tunnel-local-and-remote-port-forwarding-explained-with-examples.html).

In the document linked above, in section **Remote port forwarding**, it says

> There is one more thing you need to do to enable this. SSH doesn’t by
>   default allow remote hosts to forwarded ports. To enable this open
>   /etc/ssh/sshd_config and add the following line somewhere in that
>   config file.

So I changed `GatewayPorts no` ===> `GatewayPorts yes` and attempted to restart `SSH` as it stated. It recommends `sudo service ssh restart`, but I'm on Mac OS Sierra.

[This SO Post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/237038/os-x-terminal-command-to-turn-on-off-ssh-server) says I can start/stop ssh via

`sudo launchctl unload (or load)  /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist`

but get error

> /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist: Could not find specified
>   service

Things I've tried:

- [This article](https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/19070/load-unload-or-enable-disable-launch-agents-and-daemons-for-junos-pulse-update) says `LaunchAgents` is run as a user, not root, which I am doing.
- `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist` exists
- `launchctl` has subcommand `load` and `unload`

So what's the problem?

Comment: If you need a fix now you can just reboot your mac.

Answer (score 9):

You can restart openSSH on your mac with the following (tested on Sierra 10.12.6)

```
sudo launchctl stop com.openssh.sshd
sudo launchctl start com.openssh.sshd
```

[Source](http://vivo.pub/2409)

Answer (score 1):

or your commands work, but you need to super user do them (and I'm on High Sierra):

```
    sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
    sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
```